# Class / type of class, that was created with metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_class = type(name, bases, dct)
        new_class.attr = 100  # add some to class
        return new_class


class WithAttr(metaclass=Meta):
    pass


print(type(WithAttr))
# <class 'type'>
```

Why does it print `<class 'type'>`, but not `<class '__main__.Meta'>`
Am I right that class WithAttr is instance of Meta?

Comment: Hint: where the code says `new_class = type(name, bases, dct)`, what do you expect this to mean? Therefore, what do you expect should be the type of `new_class`, and therefore of whatever is `return`ed from `__new__`? Can you see how this relates to the `WithAttr` class?

Comment: Finding a good duplicate for this was harder than I hoped, but easier than I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're making an explicit call to `type(name, bases, dct)`, which in turn calls `type.__new__(type, name, bases, dct)`, with the `type` class passed as the first argument to the `type.__new__` method, effectively constructing an instance of `type` rather than `Meta`.

You can instead call `type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)`, passing the child class as an argument to contruct a `Meta` instance. In case `__new__` is overridden in a parent class that is a child class of `type`, call `super().__new__` instead of `type.__new__` to allow the method resolution order to be followed.

Change:

```
new_class = type(name, bases, dct)
```

to:

```
new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/KIy2qG

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the metaclass assignment and how Python handles metaclasses.

If, within `Meta.__new__`, we create the instance using `super().__new__`, the metaclass `Meta` will properly used to create the class `WithAttr`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        dct['attr'] = 100 # add an attribute to the class
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class WithAttr(metaclass=Meta):
    pass


print(type(WithAttr))  # <class '__main__.Meta'>
```

This works by ensuring that the object *returned from `__new__`* is a `Meta` instance.